# .Net Core 2.0 Log4Net AdoNetAppender isn't working

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-appender, .net-core-2.0

We have made common logging library based on Log4Net in .Net Core 2.0 
Console and FileAppender works fine but we want to log to SQ DB and trying to use AdoNetAppender, we get following error

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender' from assembly 'log4net,
>   Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'.
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
>   ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement
>   appenderElement) log4net:ERROR Appender named [AdoNetAppender] not
>   found.

Seems like AdoNetAppender isn't supported with .Net Core 2.0

It's not in the list here either: 
https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html#Appenders

Comment: I have made a package with the AdoNetAppender available for core projects. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender/ . Find how to set it up here: https://github.com/microknights/Log4NetAdoNetAppender